# UIWindow stops receiving touches after removing a subview from it

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uitouch, uiwindow

I'm using a subclass of UIWindow to handle touch event in all views of the app.
I'm trying to implement a drag and drop mechanism.

When tapping and holding on a view, i remove that view and start dragging with the finger.
problem is after i remove the view the window stop receiving touch events until i lift my finger and touch it again.

help?

EDIT:
i found that after the subview is removed, the window is receiving touches but the touch phase is UITouchPhaseStationary and not UITouchPhaseMoved, even though there is only one UITouch in [event touches];      how is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure, but I think your problem is because your are trying to handle events in `UIWindow` class, rather than `UIViewController` class. UIWindow is not designed to do so. Why don't you try this:

1. Add an instance of `UIViewController` class to your project.
2. Add the view of that `UIViewController` to your `UIWindow` instance.
3. Add the touch handling method to the `UIViewController`.
4. Add your first view to `UIViewController`.
5. Respond to touch event.
6. Remove the first view from `UIViewController`, and bring in the second view, or whatever.
   (It is kind of swapping views under the `UIViewController`, rather than in the instance of `UIWindow`.)